# nvd3 insert a break in a line chart

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js, linechart

I am using an nvd3 linechart and am looking for a way to insert a break in the plotted line.

If I have a dataset with 10 points I need the chart to draw a line connecting the first 5 points and the last 5 points but NOT connecting points 5 and 6 ie

```
1-2-3-4-5 6-7-8-9-10
```

I have tried setting both chart.defined and line.defined = false for point 5 but that results in no line connecting points 4, 5 and 6 ie

```
1-2-3-4 5 6-7-8-9-10
```

Unfortunately I have got a standalone snippet of all the code involved in rendering the chart - but here are the two functions that resulted in point 5 being rendered as a stand alone point:

```
chart = nv.models.lineChart();
chart.defined(function (d,i) {
    if (i == 4){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
}



lines.defined(function(d,i){
    if (i==4 ){
        return false
    }else{return true}
})
```

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried this far? Sharing a demo to fiddle around with is always a good idea.